# multiply numbers untill the user enters 0

Tags: c

I don't know why but the loop doesn't stop even when I enter 0. can someone help me with this?

```
    int main(void)
   {
    float number,product = 1;
    printf("Provide floats separated by a line: \n");
    scanf("%f" , &number);
    while(number != 0)
    {
            product *= number;
            if(number == 0)
                break;
        }    
    printf("The product of your values is: %.2f" , product);
    printf("\n");
    
}
```

Comment: The way the code is written, `number` can never change while the loop is running, so naturally it will run forever.

Comment: Instead of `if ... break` repeat `printf+scanf` inside the loop.

Comment: If you change the termination condition to "a non-numeric input" then the control loop can be `while(scanf("%f", &number) == 1)`. Any decent code needs to check the return value from `scanf` anyway.

Comment: I don't think `scanf` isn't really the right tool here anyway. Better separate input (`fgets` or similar) and parsing (check for "" or "\n", try `sscanf` after).

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to place the [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) call inside the loop to repeatedly ask the user for input. As it is you only ask once, and then loop forever on the same value.

Here we place the call in the predicate itself:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    float number = 0, 
          product = 1;
                                                   
    puts("Provide floats separated by a line:");      
    
    while (scanf("%f" , &number) == 1 && number)
         product *= number;
    
    printf("The product of your values is: %.2f\n" , product);
}
```

You should always check the return values of your I/O functions. [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) returns the number of conversions that took place, which here should be `1`. On error, EOF, or `number` being `0` we do not continue the loop.

Comment: Minor problem, that doesn't terminate on a blank line, only EOF (control-D on Linux) because `scanf` doesn't read space as a 0 (or a failure, just skips). I think this still qualifies as a correct answer, dealing with `scanf` behaviour is a different problem.

Comment: @JohnBayko Yeah, I'm writing a more verbose loop right now. Might be slightly overwhelming though, as the problem is less about proper error handling and edge-cases and more around misunderstanding the flow of a program.

Comment: there is still an issue with the code it is not storing the product just giving out the last entered number.

Comment: @HarsimarKaur That's certainly not the case with the program I've shown. When copying this over did you mistakenly use `number` instead of `product` in the final call to `printf`? Did you mistakenly use `=` instead of `*=`?

Comment: @Oka no...see this is my code...                                
 int main(void)
{
 float number,product = 1;
 printf("Provide floats separated by a line: \n");
 scanf("%f" , &number);
 while(scanf("%f" , &number) != 0)
 {
         product *= number;
         
        }  
 printf("The product of your values is: %.2f" , product);
 printf("\n");
 
}                                                                                      and whenever I print it in terminal it just gives the last entered number.

Comment: @HarsimarKaur You've misunderstood the return value of `scanf`: it is not the value of the matched specifier - that would not make sense as `scanf` can be used to match all kinds of types, and multiple at a time. The return value of `scanf` is the number of *conversions* that took place, that is the number of specifiers that matched our user's input. `%f` is *one* specifier, so we are looking for `1` conversion to take place.